# Cant open .doc file after download in php

Tags: php, ms-word, doc

I have a script to download files with php, and it works great. But when I download a .doc type file and I open it in MS Word it says that I have to select a encoding and most of the text is in this format:

`--- L  ß{  ß{  Gü                      ²       ÿÿ          ÿÿ          ÿÿ                  •     Ê      Ê  (       (       Ð       Ð       Ð   Ä           ÿÿÿÿ    ”¬      ”¬      ”¬      ”¬  T.  èM  ”   ”-         â   |W      ’W      ’W      ’W      ’W      ý÷      ý÷      ý÷      è  ---`

This are my headers:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: $mtype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$newFile\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);
$mtype  = application/msword
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');`.

Not sure what your `$mtype  = application/msword` is supposed to do...

And change `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$newFile\"");` to `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$newFile'."');`

After the headers just use:

```
ob_clean();
ob_end_flush();
readfile($file_path);
exit;
```

Comment: I change as you said, but it makes the same thing. And after my headers i got this code:
   $file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");

   if ($file) {
     while(!feof($file)) {
    print(fread($file, 1024*8));
    flush();
    if (connection_status()!=0) {
      @fclose($file);
      die();
    }
     }
     @fclose($file);
   }